# Percentage multi or single in qlikview

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I want to count the percentage of how many person have multi firstnames and single firstname, I tried but it works in number not in string

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this expression:
sum(Aggr(if(Count(DISTINCT prenom)>1,1,0),nom)) / Count(DISTINCT nom)

Comment: thank you I did it yesterday the same request, anyway thank you a lot for your answer.